# Is it safe to uninstall Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit?

Tags: windows-10, uninstall, deployment

[Windows 10 Pro x64 ver 1709]

In `Control Panel -> Programs and Features` I see an item `Windows Assessment and Deployment Kit - Windows 10`. Searching the web tells me this is (only) used for W10 deployement to other PCs - is this correct? Any repercussions to uninstalling it?  I do not remember ever (explicitly) installing it.  (It also reports its size as 6.77GB - would be great to reclaim that space as well, if accurate.)

Comment: I presume you installed it for a reason.  If you are no longer using the software the require it, feel free, to remove it from your system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is it safe to remove? Yes.

It is only used for deployment to other PCs - is this correct? No. It has several tools that are available for reasons other than simply deploying Windows, although it is primarily used for preparing systems for deployment. It also has tools for creating WinPE Boot discs, managing windows images, etc.

Any repercussions to uninstalling it? We can't answer that for you. If you don't know the answer to that question, then it's probably not needed.